# Южной и Северной Кореи (Корей) - правильно ли?

Tags: согласование

BBC (https://www.bbc.com/russian/news-45571191):

Порадовали Трампа: о чем договорились Северная и Южная Кореи

В столице КНДР завершились переговоры Ким Чен Ына и Мун Чжэ Ина. Главный итог - декларация о денуклеаризации. О чем еще договорились лидеры двух Корей и чему так радуется Дональд Трамп?

Радио Свобода (https://www.svoboda.org/a/29474783.html):

Северная и Южная Кореи договорились провести саммит в Пхеньяне 18–20 сентября для обсуждения "практических мер" по денуклеаризации Корейского полуострова.

НТВ (http://www.ntv.ru/novosti/2062461/):

Северная и Южная Кореи сегодня возобновили практику воссоединения семей, разделенных войной 50-х годов.

ТАСС (https://tass.ru/mezhdunarodnaya-panorama/5121740):

Между 2003 и 2008 годами, в дни так называемой "политики солнечного тепла" и беспрецедентного сближения Северной и Южной Корей, именно отсюда миллионы туристов отправлялись в КНДР, чтобы покорить живописные пики гор Кымгансан (Алмазные горы).

Правильны ли второй и третий варианты:

1. Состоялась встреча лидеров Южной Кореи и Северной Кореи.
2. Состоялась встреча лидеров Южной и Северной Кореи.
3. Состоялась встреча лидеров Южной и Северной Корей.

Можно ли так писать, чтобы не повторять "Кореи"? Русский и украинский язык и русский и английский языки - оба варианта правильны, утверждает Грамота. Или это совершенно другой случай? Ведь речь идет о написании названия государств.

Comment: Нет «Северной», есть КНДР. Корректно: «Состоялась встреча лидеров Южной Кореи и КНДР.

Comment: Официально: Республика Корея и Корейская Народно-Демократическая Республика. Южная Корея и Северная Корея — неофициальные названия, широко употребляемые в СМИ. (Википедия).

Comment: Южная Корея и КНДР — нежелательное смешение стилей.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, нет особых правил для названий государств. Все зависит от желания подчеркнуть наличие двух разных Корей или их связь и близость.

Comment: Я тоже думаю, что все варианты верны.Состоялась встреча лидеров Южной и Северной Кореи. - подчёркивается внутренняя связь между двумя Кореями, всё-таки это одна национальность - корейцы.
Состоялась встреча лидеров Южной и Северной Корей. - автор подчёркивает наличие двух государств.

Comment: @Людмила Спасибо за поддержку.